# DependencyProperty compiles and works but Intellisense doesn't think so

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

I have two custom controls/visuals and I need an `Orientation` property on both. In both cases, the default should be `"Horizontal"` but the user of the control/visual should be able to specify `Orientation="Vertical"` to arrange the components of the control/visual vertically. What I have works great on my ImageButton control, but not so well on my HeaderedLabel visual. Although both of them compile fine, Intellisense doesn't like one of them. Here's an example of their use...

```
<Visuals:ImageButton Image="Icons/ok.png" Content="Normal Content"/>
<Visuals:ImageButton Image="Icons/ok.png" Content="Vertical Content" Orientation="Vertical"/>
<Visuals:HeaderedLabel Header="Normal Header" Content="Normal Content"/>
<Visuals:HeaderedLabel Header="Vertical Header" Content="Vertical Content" Orientation="Vertical"/>
```

...which produces the following when rendered inside a vertical StackPanel:

[image: Rendered controls/visuals]

So it does what I want, but the problem is this: While Intellisense recognizes the possible options for `Orientation` for the ImageButton, ***it does not recognize the possible options for*** `Orientation` ***for the HeaderedLabel***. And while the code compiles & runs fine, ***there's a persistent error in the Visual Studio "Error List" pane:*** "'Vertical' is not a valid value for property 'Orientation'.", ***and there's a blue squiggly line under the text*** `Orientation="Vertical"` for the second HeaderedLabel in my xaml example above.

Here are the relevant files:

```
// File 'ImageButton.cs'
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Visuals
{
   public class ImageButton : Button
   {
      static ImageButton()
      {
         DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ImageButton),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ImageButton)));
      }

      public ImageSource Image
      {
         get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageProperty); }
         set { SetValue(ImageProperty, value); }
      }

      public Orientation Orientation
      {
         get { return (Orientation)GetValue(OrientationProperty); }
         set { SetValue(OrientationProperty, value); }
      }

      // Note that for ImageButton, I can just say 'Orientation.Horizontal' and
      // the compiler resolves that to System.Windows.Controls.Orientation...
      public static readonly DependencyProperty OrientationProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("Orientation", typeof(Orientation),
            typeof(ImageButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(Orientation.Horizontal));

      public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("Image", typeof(ImageSource),
            typeof(ImageButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
   }
}
```

.

```
// File 'HeaderedLabel.cs'
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Visuals
{
   public class HeaderedLabel : Control
   {
      static HeaderedLabel()
      {
         DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(HeaderedLabel),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(HeaderedLabel)));
      }

      public object Header
      {
         get { return (object)GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
         set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
      }

      public object Content
      {
         get { return (object)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
         set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
      }

      public object Orientation
      {
         get { return (object)GetValue(OrientationProperty); }
         set { SetValue(OrientationProperty, value); }
      }

      public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("Header", typeof(object), typeof(HeaderedLabel),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

      public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("Content", typeof(object), typeof(HeaderedLabel),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

      // Note that for HeaderedLabel, unlike ImageButton, I have to specify the fully-
      // qualified name of 'Orientation.Horizontal', otherwise the compiler resolves it
      // to Visuals.HeaderedLabel.Orientation and gives a compiler error...
      public static readonly DependencyProperty OrientationProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("Orientation", typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Orientation),
            typeof(HeaderedLabel), new UIPropertyMetadata(System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal));
   }
}
```

.

```
   <!-- File 'Generic.xaml' -->
   <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Visuals"
                        xmlns:bind="clr-namespace:Visuals.BindingConverters">

       <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ImageButton}">
          <Setter Property="Template">
             <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ImageButton}">
                   <Button>
                      <StackPanel Orientation="{TemplateBinding Orientation}">
                         <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Image}"/>
                         <ContentPresenter/>
                      </StackPanel>
                   </Button>
                </ControlTemplate>
             </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
       </Style>

       <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:HeaderedLabel}">
          <Setter Property="Template">
             <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:HeaderedLabel}">
                   <StackPanel Orientation="{TemplateBinding Orientation}">
                      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                         <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" />
                         <TextBlock Text=":" />
                      </StackPanel>
                      <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                   </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
             </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
       </Style>

    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Any ideas why the compiler would resolve `Orientation.Horizontal` to System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal for the ImageButton, but not for the HeaderedLabel? And more importantly, any ideas why Intellisense can't figure out the options for HeaderedLabel.Orientation?

BTW, I'm using VisualStudio 2012 and .NET Framework 4.0.

Comment: Cannot reproduce a problem with  typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Orientation) you are mentioning in comments about Dependency Property declaration, but for xaml Intellisense solution is simple: take a closer look on your ordinary property declaration. In ImageButton you have `Orientation Orientation` (right), in HeaderedLabel you have `object Orientation` (wrong)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of your properties, including the `Orientation` property, are declared as having the type `object`.

You should have this instead:

```
public Orientation Orientation
{
    get { return (Orientation)GetValue(OrientationProperty); }
    set { SetValue(OrientationProperty, value); }
}
```

The XAML editor should be able to correctly accept values of type `Orientation` if you declare the property correctly. Otherwise, it will attempt to assign a `string` value of `"Vertical"` to the property, which when passed to the `SetValue()` method will fail, because the `DependencyProperty` object itself was initialized with `Orientation` as the valid type and it has no way to convert from the `string` value to an `Orientation` value.

If you declare the property correctly, then WPF will understand automatically that it needs to convert the `string` value shown in the XAML to an `Orientation` value for the property (i.e. parse the `string` value as the appropriate `enum` type), and in that case the initialization should work.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. Stupid cut-and-paste error. Regarding the other properties, `Header` and `Content`, should those be something else, or is type `object` the best choice? (They are both just freeform strings of whatever the user wants them to be.)

Comment: Also, as you're not hurting for rep, would you prefer that I just delete this question as it's just a cut-and-paste error?

Comment: The question could arguably be closed under the "typographical error" reason, so deletion might be appropriate. That would be true regardless of how much rep I have. :) So feel free to do that, if you feel that the problem was resolved in a way that is unlikely to be helpful to other people searching Stack Overflow later. I will note that your question is the only one with both the phrase _"is not a valid value for property"_ and the word _"Intellisense"_, so do consider whether someone else could make a similar mistake and whether they would be likely to find this by searching.